# Inserting a row in between two rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with two columns subj-id,subj-name in the below format.

```
101 Maths
102 Science
103 Biology
201 Maths
202 Science
203 Biology
204 Geography
301 Maths
302 Science
```

Now i need to insert a row Physics between Maths and Science in all the places it is present and the table should look like below

```
101 maths
102 Physics
103 Biology
201 Maths
202 Physics
203 Science
204 Biology
205 Geography
301 Maths
302 Physics
303 Science
```

I have this problem from a long time. I have mentioned only three insertions here. In the actual problem I need to have such insertions between Maths and Science at more than 50 places. It is very difficult to do it manually.
Can any one guide me the approach that needs to follow to handle this scenario.

Comment: WHY do you need to redo the ids?

Comment: is this row data or columns provided?  Is it postgresql or mysql? you have both tagged

Comment: There's no reason you need to do this in a database. The beauty of using a database is that you can query and shape the data however you like. You would just do an order by.

Comment: From your description... wouldnt it be 101 Math, 102 Physics, 103 science, 104 biology?

Comment: For this data Excel should do.... ;)

Comment: The OP has not clearly described his requirements. This question is beyond the scope of SO

Comment: @AlexandreSantos I have the problem for different values. The question was a similar one. I need it to get inserted only between the two mentioned places and it should be in an order.

Comment: This is an application problem, not a database problem. When you insert a new course, compute your new numbers in the application and apply them to the database as an `INSERT` and a series of `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: @subhamsoni I need to insert in the above format at 50 such places which cannot be done manually. Edited the same in the question

Comment: is the data "101 Maths", or "101", "Maths"?  You haven't really given a whole lot of information of what your issue is or why it needs to be changed.  There might be more useful responses if you'd elaborate on the problem and the intended solution

Comment: @tadman I have already have such table of 5000 rows which is already created and its very difficult to recreate the entire table.

Answer (score 4):

A SQL table represents an *unordered* set.  There is no concept of "in-between" (or first or last or previous or next).  The rows simply are; they are in the table.

Queries return *result sets* that have an order.  And, you can control the order when you write the query.  That is why you use the `order by` clause.  When you write:

```
select *
from mytable;
```

The results are in any order that the database wants to return them.  There are simply no guarantees.  Instead, query the database as:

```
select *
from mytable
order by col1;
```

And you will get the data properly ordered.

The moral of the story:  just insert the data into the table.  When you query it, use an `order by` clause to get the results in your desired order.

Comment: I already have a table of 5000 rows and I need to insert some rows at 50 places as mentioned in the question, which cannot be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm.

It doesn't seem you are using rows and columns as they are intended in a database.

However, a solution for your problem would be doing this:

For every Math, start on a new row:

```
ID  Stuff
100 Maths Science Biology
200 Maths Science Biology Geography
300 Maths Science
```

To read this data structure you would start with the first index and add 1 for each entry in the string.

For example, when "expanded",

```
100 Maths Science Biology
```

would become

```
Maths = ID + 1
Science = ID + 2
Biology = ID + 3
```

...

Now, adding a new `Stuff`:

When a new stuff is added, find the place where it should go between and insert it there, then when you "expand" the strings again, the newly inserted one will be in order.

```
100 Maths Physics Science Biology
```

would become

```
Maths = ID + 1    = 101
Physics = ID + 2  = 102
Science = ID + 3  = 103
Biology = ID + 4  = 104
```

...

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted relational databases are not really meant to work with ordered lists.
You could work out some convoluted solution like select the "math" rows followed by "science" rows and then use that to insert "Physics" row.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table AS
(
(SELECT 
t1.id+1 AS id,
'Physics' AS course
FROM 
table t1 JOIN table t2 
ON 
t1.course='Maths' AND t2.course='Science' AND t1.id+1=t2.id)
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE)
```

And then work something to update other labels maybe using rank() windowed function.